# Rails update model settings without leaving the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-console

I'm tired of exiting the rails console to update the changes done to the model, re-entering and having to set all variables previously set. Is there a better way to update model settings without leaving the console?

Comment: Have you tried with [`reload!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/ConsoleMethods.html#method-i-reload-21) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the command: `reload!`

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/ConsoleMethods.html#method-i-reload-21